# XML: Show two child nodes with the same name in php

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have a problem with showing my xml into a php page. I have an xml that looks like this (obviously its only a part of it because it really to long to post it all). 
It all goes well until it cames to the "genre", I have two values for it and I don't know how to show them at the same time.

```
<movie>
     <id>4441</id>
     <title>Rudderless</title>
     <title_long>Rudderless (2014)</title_long>
     <year>2014</year>
     <rating>7.5</rating>
     <runtime>105</runtime>
<genres>
   <genre>Comedy</genre>
   <genre>Drama</genre>
</genres>
</movie>
```

(an important thing to notice is that not every movie will have two genre, sometimes there is only one and sometime two or three)
This is my code right now

```
$genere = array();
foreach ($xml->data->movies->movie->genres as $row) {
    foreach ($row->children() as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == "genre") {
            $genere[] = $val;
        }
    }
}
//and then I'll print
for ($i = 0; $i < 20 ; $i++) {
    echo "<div class=text><b>" . $genere[$i] . "</b></div>";
}
```

When I'm doing this it will print only for the first item of the array, and the others just give me a "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /path/ on line 53"

I've tried to follow some guides but it was a failure

What am I doing wrong?

/--Edit--/

```
<?php

 $xml = simplexml_load_file("https://yts.to/api/v2/list_movies.xml")
 $titolo = array();
$locandina = array();
    $anno = array();
    $durata = array();
    $genere = array();

    foreach ($xml->data->movies->movie as $element) 
    {
        foreach($element->children() as $key => $val) 
        {
            $chiave = $key;
            $valore = $val;
            if ($key == "title")
            {
                $titolo[] = $val ;
            }   
            if ($key == "medium_cover_image")
            {
                $locandina[] = $val ;
            }   
            if ($key == "year")
            {
                $anno[] = $val ;
            }   
            if ($key == "runtime")
            {
                $durata[] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
foreach ($xml->data->movies->movie->genres as $row) 
    {
        foreach($row->children() as $key => $val) 
        {
            if ($key == "genre")
            {
                $genere[] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
    var_dump($genere);

    for ($i=0 ; $i<20 ; $i++)
    {
        echo "<div class=totbox>";
        echo "<div class=box><img src=" . $locandina[$i] . "></div>";
        echo "<div class=text><b>" . $titolo[$i] . "</b> - " . $anno[$i] . "</div>";
        echo "<div class=text><b>" . $genere[$i] . "</b></div>";
        echo "<div class=text><b> Durata:" . $durata[$i] . "</b></div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is result if you execute after foreach: var_dump($genere)? Put here working code it will be better to test it. Im not sure if you dont need to get childrens from $xml->data->movies->movie->genres, not from $row. But make it work for us, so we can test it

Comment: Hi Daimos, I've tried and it gives me this

`array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#89 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Horror"
  }
}`

It looks like it only process the first one and stops there.

Comment: if you prepare working piece of code i will help you

Comment: I'll edit the first post including in it the working code.

Comment: updated answer, put your genre loop inside movie loop

Comment: Why do you assign the values to `$titolo = array();...$genere = array();` anyway? It doesn't look like you're doing much with the data but immediately iterate over it and print it. You could do just that in the first loop(-cluster) when traversing the xml model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED - Code fixed. Please, try now.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://yts.to/api/v2/list_movies.xml")
$titolo = array();
$locandina = array();
$anno = array();
$durata = array();
$genere = array();

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($xml->data->movies->movie as $element) {
        foreach ($element->children() as $key => $val) {
            $chiave = $key;
            $valore = $val;
            if ($key == "title") {
                $titolo[] = $val;
            }
            if ($key == "medium_cover_image") {
                $locandina[] = $val;
            }
            if ($key == "year") {
                $anno[] = $val;
            }
            if ($key == "runtime") {
                $durata[] = $val;
            }
            if ($key == "genres") {

                for($g = 0; $g < count($xml->data->movies->movie[$i]->genres->genre); $g++) {
                        $genere[$i][] = $xml->data->movies->movie[$i]->genres->genre[$g];
                }
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }



    for ($i = 0; $i < count($titolo); $i++) {
        echo "<div class=totbox>";
        if (isset($locandina[$i])) {
            echo "<div class=box><img src=" . $locandina[$i] . "></div>";
        }
        echo "<div class=text><b>" . $titolo[$i] . "</b> - " . $anno[$i] . "</div>";
        foreach ($genere[$i] as $genResult) {
            echo "<div class=text><b>" . $genResult . "</b></div>";
        }

        echo "<div class=text><b> Durata:" . $durata[$i] . "</b></div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, when I do this it tells me "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in \path\ on line 54"

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look on my code, based on yours. PHP file:

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('test.xml'));
$genere = array();
foreach ($xml->genres as $row) {
    foreach ($row->children() as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == "genre") {
            $genere[] = $val;
        }
    }
}
//and then I'll print
foreach ($genere as $genre) {
    echo "<div class=text><b>" . $genre . "</b></div>";
}
```

XML file:

```
<movie>
     <id>4441</id>
     <title>Rudderless</title>
     <title_long>Rudderless (2014)</title_long>
     <year>2014</year>
     <rating>7.5</rating>
     <runtime>105</runtime>
<genres>
   <genre>Comedy</genre>
   <genre>Drama</genre>
</genres>
</movie>
```

Its work fine, test it.

Based on your full xml file, look on this:

```
<genres>
<genre>Horror</genre>
</genres>
```

You have only one genre on first position, so its work fine. You need to loop on movie tag first, not genres. So put your genre tag inside movie foreach.

Like:

```
    foreach($element->children() as $key => $val) 
    {
        if ($key == "genres")
        {
            // your loop, based on $val variable!
        }
```

Comment: Uhm can you tell me where I need to be doing the loop on the movie tag? You mean in the foreach ($xml->genres as $row) { ?

Comment: answer edited. 'foreach ->movie is your place', where you iterate all elements, So insert genre loop there, based on $element.